# Using jQuery plugins in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am using an admin template theme which offers notifications. You can show them this way:

```
$.Notification.notify('success','top left','XXX', 'YYYY');
```

Now I want to trigger this notification from my angular2 components.

How to do this?

**// EDIT:**

I have installed jQuery typings via tsd install jQuery and include it this way:

```
///<reference path="../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
```

But now I get this error:

[image]

Comment: [might help](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-jquery-with-angular-2.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you don't want to implement the whole shebang of that `Notification` plugin, so an easy fix would be adding that property to the type definition file.

So open up `typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts` and search for `interface JQueryStatic {`.

Just below the interface declaration add the property like this, so TypeScript doesn't complain anymore:

```
interface JQueryStatic {

    // Notification plugin
    Notification: any;
```

In the current version of the `jquery.d.ts` type definition file that would be [line 624](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts#L624).

Comment: Thank you. Notification is now "found" but now I get another error: platform-browser.umd.js:937 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: $.notify is not a function

Comment: In your question it was `$.Notification.notify(...)`. But if it's not a function at runtime, then that plugin isn't loaded, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You have a very easy way to fix that. JQuery is a JavaScript library, if you want to use any javascript library into a typescript file, you just have to declare a variable under the import statements of your typescript file like the following :

```
import {SomeThing} from '...';

declare var jQuery:any;
declare var $:any;
```

Then you can just calling JQuery and the different plugins the following way :

```
$.Notification.notify('success','top left','XXX', 'YYYY');
```

or

```
jQuery.Notification.notify('success','top left','XXX', 'YYYY');
```

Enjoy!